# Data cleaning in a csv file using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science, data-cleaning

Hi I am working on a csv file having several columns. One particular column is address which is in the below format -

10515, 115th Place Northeast, Juanita, Kirkland, King County, Washington, 98033, United States of America

I want to split each column based on (,) and create new relevant columns for each like Unit, Street, state, post code etc...

I was able to split them based on (,) and now I have one column for each split.

The problem is that this data is not consistent, the total columns that I get after split is 10. But the data is not in the same order. Some records are like the following -

3008, 38th Avenue Southwest, West Seattle, Seattle, King County, Washington, 98126, United States of America

23098, Northeast 130th Street, Trilogy, Union Hill-Novelty Hill, Novelty, King County, Washington, 98053, United States of America

Fire Station 34, 633, 32nd Avenue East, Broadmoor, Washington Park, Seattle, King County, Washington, 98112, United States of America

Basically, not each record will have all the 10 kinds of information and not necessarily in the same order.

What should be the best approach to clean this type of data? I want to eventually have the data put in the relevant column according to what they represent, like if city go under city column, if postcode move to postcode columns etc.

I am using Python 2.0.

Hoping to get a good solution. Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, this sort of problem is usually solved by paying a human brain to sanitize the data. Even if you come up with a solution for this dataset, how will you detect when it breaks and commits bad data that only a human will recognize? If a human has to fix it after then a human may as well fix it first.

Comment: True, but the problem mentioned can be fixed by automation to a larger extent and then eventually work manually on the errors. Just trying to reduce the amount of manual effort this will require. Consider the solution I am asking for as a filter to get as much data correct as much possible. Hope this makes sense ")

Comment: This is assuming that your clean-up doesn't just introduce large numbers of hard-to-spot or subtle unexpected errors that are even harder for a human to grok. Clearly, this is a trade-off. How much data vs. how accepting of introduced errors, among other criteria. But compare with various "big" datasets being used right now. The error rate for much of the (for example) urban street data is huge, because there are no good ways to automate the cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the library `usaddress` to decompose an address into its constituent parts.

https://usaddress.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
>>> import usaddress
>>> usaddress.tag('Robie House, 5757 South Woodlawn Avenue, Chicago, IL 60637')
(OrderedDict([
   ('BuildingName', 'Robie House'),
   ('AddressNumber', '5757'),
   ('StreetNamePreDirectional', 'South'),
   ('StreetName', 'Woodlawn'),
   ('StreetNamePostType', 'Avenue'),
   ('PlaceName', 'Chicago'),
   ('StateName', 'IL'),
   ('ZipCode', '60637')]),
'Street Address')

>>> usaddress.tag('State & Lake, Chicago')
(OrderedDict([
   ('StreetName', 'State'),
   ('IntersectionSeparator', '&'),
   ('SecondStreetName', 'Lake'),
   ('PlaceName', 'Chicago')]),
'Intersection')

>>> usaddress.tag('P.O. Box 123, Chicago, IL')
(OrderedDict([
   ('USPSBoxType', 'P.O. Box'),
   ('USPSBoxID', '123'),
   ('PlaceName', 'Chicago'),
   ('StateName', 'IL')]),
'PO Box')
```

from there, you can query the returned dictionary and readily put it in your pandas DataFrame.

Comment: it's `usaddress`, not `usaaddress` (one A, not 2)

Comment: I used usaddress and got the output as following - (OrderedDict([('AddressNumber', '10515'), ('StreetName', '115th'), ('StreetNamePostType', 'Place'), ('StreetNamePostDirectional', 'Northeast'), ('Recipient', 'Juanita, Kirkland, King County, Washington, 98033, United States of America')]), 'Street Address') .... Its not splitting according to the attributes shown in your code.  Taking one tag as Recipient and putting multiple kinds of information in it.

Comment: Also, it eventually throws an error saying - RepeatedLabelError: 
ERROR: Unable to tag this string because more than one area of the string has the same label

Comment: Using the usaddress.parse(), I get the following output -                     [('10515,', 'AddressNumber'), ('115th', 'StreetName'), ('Place', 'StreetNamePostType'), ('Northeast,', 'StreetNamePostDirectional'), ('Juanita,', 'Recipient'), ('Kirkland,', 'Recipient'), ('King', 'Recipient'), ('County,', 'Recipient'), ('Washington,', 'Recipient'), ('98033,', 'Recipient'), ('United', 'Recipient'), ('States', 'Recipient'), ('of', 'Recipient'), ('America', 'Recipient')]
.......................Any idea why it is happening like this?

Comment: This may be a subject for another question.